# 2 suspicious «non existent» tasks named 0000:06:00.0_di and 0000:06:00.0_ev. What are they?

Tags: kernel, pci, hacking

In an UBUNTU 18.04 installation here are two suspicious «non existent» tasks named `0000:06:00.0_di` and `0000:06:00.0_ev`. Log indicates that a problematic pci `0000:06:00.0` exists, but still there is no indication on how such a task started (task list says that command line was `0000:06:00.0_di` and `0000:06:00.0_ev`). Links to print screens [task list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tCxa.png), [about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuiKa.png) and [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lesMh.png).

Comment: mvsas is the name of the pci ssd driver, do ou have a pci ssd device? FYI you can open a program in english like this `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 gnome-system-monitor` with LANG var as a prefix for a command

Comment: No ssd. For the print screens, I received them (so no access to "producer"). Apart of that, I assume that anyone which is not familiar with these screens, in any language, probably will not provide «helpful» info.

Comment: There is no ssd? So you know now on what to focus on

Comment: This is an asus P6T pro  m/b which has a (not being used) raid.

Comment: "Am I been hacked?" No. Edited the title to a more sensible one. Leave paranoia away from questions please. Either proof you have been hacked or assume you are not to start with.

Answer (score 0):

This processes belongs to a scsi device on your system.

You can use `hwinfo` or `find /sys -name \*0000:06:00.0\*` or `lsscsi -v` on your system to identify it.

I have (no ubuntu) 0000:08:00.0 processes and it is a Tape Drive:

```
# ps axuww | grep 0000:08:00.0
root       659  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jul30   0:00 [0000:08:00.0_ev]
root       660  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jul30   0:00 [0000:08:00.0_di]

# find /sys -name \*0000:08:00.0\*
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:08:00.0
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:08:00.0
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/mvsas/0000:08:00.0

# lsscsi -v
[1:0:0:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 5-SCSI   Z64D  /dev/st0 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/1:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:08:00.0/host1/port-1:0/end_device-1:0/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0]
```